# How to change the default distro directory in WSL?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two drives on my machine , C, and D. On setting up a WSL2 image on one occasion and a WSL2-backed docker image on another, I found my C drive was full. I was able to move over one of the images to my larger drive using the `wsl --export`, `wsl --unregister`, and `wsl --import` commands. But what I really want is to change the defaults so all future docker and non-docker WSL2 images are created on my larger drive. Is it possible to change WSL2's default image location?

I've looked through the `wsl` documentation and I haven't been able to find anything so far.

UPDATE:
Actually, it looks like migrating the docker-desktop-data distro may have permanently changed the location for docker instances, though I'm guessing not for instances created directly through WSL or the MS Store.

Comment: You can use Windows Store application to choose which drive WSL instances are installed to

Comment: @Ramhound Any idea where that setting is? I can't find it.